# Elegant Solution to an OOP Issue involving type-changing in python

Tags: python, oop, rotation

I run into an OOP problem when coding something in python that I don't know how to address in an elegant solution. I have a class that represents the equation of a line (`y = mx + b`) based on the `m` and `b` parameters, called `Line`. Vertical lines have infinite slope, and have equation `x = c`, so there is another class `VerticalLine` which only requires a `c` parameter. Note that I am unable to have a `Line` class that is represented by two points in the xy-plane, if this were a solution I would indeed use it.

I want to be able to rotate the lines. Rotating a horizontal line by `pi/2 + k*pi` (`k` an integer) results in a vertical line, and vice versa. So a normal `Line` would have to somehow be converted to a `VerticalLine` in-place, which is impossible in python (well, not impossible but incredibly wonky). How can I better structure my program to account for this problem?

Note that other geometric objects in the program have a rotation method that is in-place, and they are already used frequently, so if I could I would like the line rotation methods to also be in place. Indeed, this would be a trivial problem if the line rotation methods could return a new rotated `Line` or `VerticalLine` object as seen fit.

Answer (score 0):

Geometric objects that have a fixed boundary/end-points can be translated and rotated in place. But for a line, unless you talk about a line from point A to point B with a fixed length, you are looking at both end-points either being at `infinity` or `-infinity` (`y = mx + c`). Division using `infinity` or `-infinity` is not simple math and hence I believe complicates the rotation and translation algorithms